# Get the number of keys values from elastic search through API

Tags: elasticsearch

I have posted data on elastic search. I am able to get total data as JSON and count of responses but the problem I am facing is when i have posted the information of some college with attributes like branch, faculty. where key is stored as branch and eg like CSE, ECE will be the value. I want to know what all branches are available and also count of branches available in that particular organisation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggs function on term branch that will return the branch field as group by sample is

```
GET db/_search
{
 "aggs": {
    "Branch": : {
      "top_hits": {
        "_source": {
          "includes": [
            "branch"
          ]
        }
    }
}
```